# Toilet tank draining near fill valve gasket

Tags: toilet

My toilet's tank is draining and I have an idea as to why.

(I should clarify - this is a dual flush!)

I opened it up and dropped a bit of food colouring in – the colouring made it's way to **the base of the fill valve**.

I drained the tank and got up close to take a picture of the area I suspected to be the cause of the tank draining out.

Towards the left edge you can see that the gasket isn't quite as sealed as it is around the rest of it.

What is the best way to address this? Chewing gum? Some sort of toilet-tank specific caulking? Any advice is appreciated.

[image: Base of toilet's fill valve]

Comment: You say the tank is "draining" but where to? If the fill valve area you indicate was the problem, the tank would drain **onto the floor**, is this the case?

Comment: Hey Jimmy, no, it isn't draining onto the floor, but into the toilet bowl.